# Other user Facebook feed error

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, codenameone

I am trying to fetch facebook feed using graph api in Codename one but it only works with my own account, Whenever other user will try to fetch their feed using my app it throw an error.

Following is my code

```
public class Test {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    Form facebook;
    Toolbar tb;
    Image user;
    Label userLabel;
    Label username;
    Login loginfb;
    String clientId = "158093724691158";
    String redirectURI = "http://www.codenameone.com/";
    String clientSecret = "4f5b275ae702f7b6fde9bc50bfe3b5e3";
    Label proLabel;
    Label fname;
    Label fmail;
    Label fgender;
    Container container12;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        try{
        Splash spl = new Splash();
        spl.show();

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                facebook.show();
            }
        } , 4000);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       facebook = new Form("Facebook", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        tb = new Toolbar();
        facebook.setToolbar(tb);

       user = theme.getImage("user.png");
        userLabel = new Label(user);
        username = new Label("Visitor");
        Button facebooklogin = new Button("Login with Facebook");
        Button linked = new Button("Login with LinkedIn");
        //linked.setUIID("linkedButton");

        linked.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                          Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code", 
                "81lq3qpacjvkcu", 
                "https://www.codenameone.com","r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress","https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken","vzwWfamZ3IUQsJQL");
        Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);
        auth2.showAuthentication(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getSource() instanceof String) {
                    String token = (String) evt.getSource();
                    String expires = Oauth2.getExpires();

                    System.out.println("Token=" +token + "Expires in " +expires );

                } else {
                    Exception err = (Exception) evt.getSource();
                    err.printStackTrace();
                    Dialog.show("Error", "An error occurred while logging in: " + err, "OK", null);
                }
            }
        });

       }
        });

        facebooklogin.addActionListener((evt) -> {

              Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
                fb.setClientId(clientId);
                fb.setRedirectURI(redirectURI);
                fb.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
                fb.setScope("user_birthday,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_hometown,user_location,user_likes,user_education_history,user_work_history,user_website,user_events,user_photos,user_videos,user_friends,user_about_me,user_status,user_games_activity,user_tagged_places,user_posts,rsvp_event,email,read_insights,publish_actions,read_audience_network_insights,read_custom_friendlists,user_action.books,user_action.music,user_action.video,user_action.news,user_action.fitness,user_managed_groups,manage_pages,pages_manage_cta,pages_manage_instant_articles,pages_show_list,publish_pages,read_page_mailboxes,ads_management,ads_read,business_management,pages_messaging,pages_messaging_phone_number,pages_messaging_subscriptions,pages_messaging_payments,public_profile");
                loginfb = fb;
                fb.setCallback(new LoginListener(LoginListener.FACEBOOK));
                if(!fb.isUserLoggedIn()){
                    fb.doLogin();
                }else{
                    showFacebookUser(fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }
        });

         Container container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY(userLabel,username);
        container1.setUIID("container1");
        tb.addComponentToSideMenu(container1);
        tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
         tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Shop by Category", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD_SHOPPING_CART, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
          tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Todays Deals", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LOCAL_OFFER, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
           tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Orders", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BOOKMARK_BORDER, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
            tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Wish List", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIST, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
             tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Account", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCOUNT_BOX, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
              tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Gift Cards", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_CARD_GIFTCARD, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
               tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Setting", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
                tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Logout", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BACKSPACE, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {

        });


        Tabs tab = new Tabs();
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
        FontImage icon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_VPN_KEY, s);
        FontImage icon2 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIST, s);
        FontImage icon3 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCOUNT_BOX, s);

        Container container11 = BoxLayout.encloseY(facebooklogin,linked);
container12 = BoxLayout.encloseY(new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab2"));


Image pro = theme.getImage("user.png");
proLabel = new Label(pro);
Label uname = new Label("Name: ");
fname = new Label("");
Label umail = new Label("Name: ");
fmail = new Label("");
Label ugender = new Label("Name: ");
fgender = new Label("");
Container profileContainer = TableLayout.encloseIn(2, uname,fname,umail,fmail,ugender,fgender);


Container container13 = BoxLayout.encloseY(proLabel,profileContainer);

        tab.addTab("Log In",icon1,container11 );
        tab.addTab("Wall",icon2, container12 );
        tab.addTab("User Profile",icon3, container13);

        facebook.add(tab);

    }

    public void showFacebookUser(String token){
        ConnectionRequest conn = new ConnectionRequest(){
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

                Map<String, Object> parsed = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));

                String email = null;
                   if(email == null){
                        email=" ";
                    }
              email = (String) parsed.get("email");
               String name = (String) parsed.get("name");
                String first_name = (String) parsed.get("first_name");
                String last_name = (String) parsed.get("last_name");
                  String gender = (String) parsed.get("gender");
                String image = (String) ((Map) ((Map) parsed.get("picture")).get("data")).get("url").toString();
                 ArrayList<String>  data_arr1= (ArrayList) ((Map) parsed.get("feed")).get("data");
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data_arr1);


                  Log.p("First NAme : " + first_name);
                Log.p("Last Name : " + last_name);
       Log.p("Email : " + email);
        Log.p("Full Name : " + name);
          Log.p("Gender : " + gender);
             Log.p("Picture : " +image);
         username.setText(name);
        userLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage((EncodedImage) user, "Small_"+image, image, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));     
      proLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage((EncodedImage) user, image, image, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE)); 
        fname.setText(name);
        fmail.setText(email);
        fgender.setText(gender);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
        JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(array.toString());
        for(int i =0; i<array2.length() ; i++){
            JSONObject jsonobject = array2.getJSONObject(i);



                   String story = null;
                   if(story == null){
                        story=" ";
                    }
                    try {
                        story = jsonobject.getString("story");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                    String msg = null;
                    if(msg == null){
                        msg=" ";
                    }
                    try {
                        msg = jsonobject.getString("message");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                    String full_picture = null;
                    if(full_picture == null){
                        full_picture=" ";
                    }
                    try{
                        full_picture = jsonobject.getString("full_picture");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            Log.p(story);
            Log.p(msg);
            Log.p(full_picture);

            Image wallimage = theme.getImage("blank.jpg");
            Label wallimageLabel = new Label(wallimage);
            wallimageLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage((EncodedImage) wallimage, full_picture, full_picture, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));
            Label wallstory = new Label(story);

            Label wallmessage = new Label(msg);
            Container wallcontainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(wallmessage,wallstory,wallimageLabel);
            container12.add(wallcontainer);

        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }



        };
         conn.setPost(false);
        conn.setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me");
        conn.addArgumentNoEncoding("access_token", token); //this statement is used to patch access token with url
        conn.addArgumentNoEncoding("fields", "email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture.width(512).height(512),feed{name,full_picture,message,story},posts");
        //above statement is used to provide permission through url so server send data with respect ot permissions.
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(conn);



    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public class LoginListener extends LoginCallback {

        public static final int FACEBOOK = 0;

        private int loginType;

        public LoginListener(int loginType) {
            this.loginType = loginType;
        }

        public void loginSuccessful() {

            try {
                AccessToken token = loginfb.getAccessToken();
                if (loginType == FACEBOOK) {
                    showFacebookUser(token.getToken());
                } 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            Dialog.show("Login Failed", errorMessage, "Ok", null);
        }
    }


}
```

And throws following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.grv.test.Test$3.readResponse(Test.java:220)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:733)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.grv.test.Test$3.readResponse(Test.java:220)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:733)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I just want to know that why this application not able to fetch facebook feed from other user account.

Comment: Thanks @jen for your response.

Comment: The very first thing you need to go do right now, is reset your app secret via app dashboard - because you just exposed it here, so everybody reading this now has a valid app access token for your app.

Comment: Did you get that massive amount of permissions your app is asking for approved in review already?

Comment: I did it already

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when I remove that setScope() method, then the app will throw the same error. And in JSON response it doesn't have feed Object.

Comment: Why would you remove that method call? Your app _needs_ permission from the user to access their data. And if you want to be able to ask users that do not have a role in the app for those permissions, then you need to get them reviewed first.

Comment: How can I get them to review?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139334/discussion-between-grv-droid-and-cbroe).

Comment: And suppose I don't want to review my app so can there is another way to use my app publicaly.

Comment: No, there is not. Facebook introduced review to be able to check if app developers are playing by the rules, and are not abusing permissions for stuff that is not allowed. If there was a way around that, the whole process would be useless.